# How to update gtable at gWidget in R?

Tags: r, gwidgets, gtable

I'm struggling to update the table data in the following code for GUI. It works to add each new request to the previous, so that it doesn't fit the screen, while I need to replace old request with the new one. Thanks! A.

```
require ( gWidgets )
options ( guiToolkit="RGtk2" )
window <- gwindow ( "Pilot>>" , visible = FALSE, horizontal = FALSE )
paned <- gpanedgroup ( cont = window )
group <- ggroup ( cont = paned, horizontal = FALSE  )
glabel ( "FPC:" , cont = group )
entry <- gedit ( "" , cont = group )
entry [ ] <- actfpc$CURFPC ##list of codes for auto-filling
search_button <- gbutton ( "Go!" , cont = group )
addSpring ( group )
frame <- gframe ( "Supply:" , cont = paned , horizontal = FALSE,use.scrollwindow=TRUE )
addHandlerChanged ( search_button , handler = function ( h , ... ) {
    ##Data subset for entered value
    a<-skulist[skulist$FPC==svalue(entry),]
    a<-a[c("X_id","FPC","STATUS","COMMENT","DCTR","DCSTOCK")]
    tbl <- gtable ( a , cont = frame, expand=TRUE )
        } )
size ( frame) <- c ( 950 , 250)
visible ( window ) <- TRUE
```

Comment: Use `[<-` to update the data displayed by `gtable` (as you would do with a data frame). You might have issues, as columns need to remain the same type. If you wish to restructure the data displayed, you can remove the old widget with `delete` and replace a new one.

Comment: @jverzani want to expand that into an answer?

Comment: If `tbl <- gtable(mtcars, cont=...)` say, then you should be able to modify a single value via `tbl[1,1] <- 12`, or replace the entire data set, with something like `tbl[] <- mtcars[1:2, 1:4]`.